# Order two dictionaries based on the keys

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, dictionary

I've got two dictionaries with the same keys.
The first one contains the count to a specific key and the second one is like a lookup, it contains the real "values" to the specific key.

Here is an example:

**1. dict:**

```
Key:    Value:

0;       10
1;       17
2;       3
3;       28
4;       8
```

**2. dict:**

```
Key:    Value:

0;       String1
1;       String2
2;       String3
3;       String4
4;       String5
```

Now I need to order these dictionaries by the value of the 1. dictionary. I know how to order just the first one but i don't have an idea how to do it for the second dictionary.

The expected output is:

**1. dict:**

```
Key:    Value:

0;       28
1;       17
2;       10
3;       8
4;       3
```

**2. dict:**

```
Key:    Value:

0;       String4
1;       String2
2;       String1
3;       String5
4;       String3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I need the keys, its for charting and these are like "fake"-values for the axis

Comment: @VishalSuthar just to order the first dictionary by the value. I had no other idea

Comment: A dictionary has no (guranateed) order and you should never rely on a dictionary to **have** any specific order.

Comment: @DanielRose The same would apply for ordering the second dictionary. What is the issue with that ?

Comment: Anyway why do the keys change? Isn´t the item with key = 3 the one with highest value in dict1? Having said this I´d expect the keys of the sorted dictionary to be 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @VishalSuthar the second dictionary has to be sorted/ordered based on the value of the first one, thats my problem

Comment: @HimBromBeere normally it would be like that, but not in my case its hard to explain without writing a large text here

Comment: And how do you expect anyone to help you if you don´t provide all relevant information?

Comment: @HimBromBeere thats not relevant for the solution, i provided all necessary information

Comment: The idea of sorting a dictionary seems strange to me. Do you maybe want a list of elements from `dict 2` sorted by the numbers in `dict 1`?

Comment: It seems your keys don´t have any purpose as you´re changing them anyway. So why not rethinking your design to assign the actual values and their number together, instead of synchronizing two dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

Well, dictionaries (like these)

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, int>() {
  {0, 10},
  {1, 17},
  {2,  3},
  {3, 28},
  {4,  8}, 
};

var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
  {0, "String 1"},
  {1, "String 2"},
  {2, "String 3"},
  {3, "String 4"},
  {4, "String 5"}, 
};
```

*doesn't have* any *order*. However, we can represent (with a help of *Linq*) data sorted:

```
  // Just an OrderBy...
  var result1 = dict1
    .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value);

  // It may appear, that dict1 doesn't have corresponding value
  // that's why we have to introduce "found" variable
  var result2 = dict2
    .Select(pair => {
      bool found = dict1.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out var value);

      return new {
        pair,
        found,
        value
      };
    })
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.found)
    .ThenByDescending(item => item.value)
    .Select(item => item.pair);

 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result1); 
 Console.WriteLine();
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result2);
```

**Outcome:**

```
[3, 28]
[1, 17]
[0, 10]
[4, 8]
[2, 3]

[3, String 4]
[1, String 2]
[0, String 1]
[4, String 5]
[2, String 3]
```

In case you want to enumerate `Value`s only (without `Key`s) we can add one more `Select`:

```
.Select((pair, i) => $"{i + 1}; {pair.Value}");
```

Like this:

```
var result1 = dict1
    .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value)
    .Select((pair, i) => $"{i + 1}; {pair.Value}");

var result2 = dict2
    .Select(pair => {
      bool found = dict1.TryGetValue(pair.Key, out var value);

      return new {
        pair,
        found,
        value
      };
    })
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.found)
    .ThenByDescending(item => item.value)
    .Select(item => item.pair)
    .Select((pair, i) => $"{i + 1}; {pair.Value}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
1; 28
2; 17
3; 10
4; 8
5; 3

1; String 4
2; String 2
3; String 1
4; String 5
5; String 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If `key` would be same for both the dictionary with same sequence then this would be the design.
Combine two dictionary into one and order them and then generate the sequence number on that.

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, String>();
dict1.Add(10, "string1");
dict1.Add(17, "string2");
dict1.Add(3, "string3");
dict1.Add(28, "string4");
dict1.Add(8, "string5");

var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, String>();
int i = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> author in dict1.OrderByDescending(key => key.Key))
{
    dict2.Add(i, author.Value);
    i++;
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> author in dict2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", author.Key, author.Value);
}
```

[DEMO](https://rextester.com/SJHF48636)